# How to include scope of classes in rspec?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I need to write rspec tests for classes in modules with somewhat deep hierarchy. And I end up typing modules names each time I need to create instance of a class. For example

File `my_site/feature_x/formatter.rb`:

```
module MySite
  module FeatureX
    class Formatter
      def format(message)
        "#{message.from} to #{message.to}: #{message.body}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

File `my_site/feature_y/data_types/message.rb`:

```
module MySite
  module FeatureY
    module DataTypes
      class Message
        attr_accessor :from, :to, :body
      end
    end
  end
end
```

File `spec/my_site/feature_x/formatter_spec.rb`:

```
require 'my_site/feature_x/formatter'
require 'my_site/feature_y/data_types/message'

describe MySite::FeatureX::Formatter do
  let (:formatter) { MySite::FeatureX::Formatter.new }

  context "#format" do
    it "should format message" do
      msg = MySite::FeatureY::DataTypes::Message.new
      msg.from = "me"
      msg.to = "you"
      msg.body = "hello"
      res = formatter.format(msg)
      expect(res).to eq("me to you: hello")
    end
  end
end
```

In this example I can declare `msg` in `let` but still will need to type its full namespaces. If I would need more instances of `Message` than each time I would have to include namespaces too.

To my taste having lengthy modules decreases readability. Simply `Formatter` or `Message` express the essence, when `MySite::FeatureX::Formatter` or `MySite::FeatureY::DataTypes::Message` make reading harder. Is there a simple idiomatic way how to bring classes in the test context without having to type modules for that classes?

Comment: I'd say you're doing it right, add whatever is long to type to a variable and then call whatever methods on that (as you are). The other option is really just to change your module/class layout, if you think reading the modules is hard then I'm guessing the module structure is too complicated (of course it could be required complexity, depends on the problem domain).

Comment: In my current project there are at least 3 levels of modules and not a lot of options to change that.

Comment: Well you could always just make some test helpers to all of the classes that you want, eg. `def message; MySite::FeatureY::DataTypes::Message; end` but that's it I think (so you're always gonna have to type it once, but if you keep it DRY it'll only be once+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specs are fine, it's just the module layout that's tripping you up.

1. Consider changing the structure of your modules/classes to make it easier to use.
2. Create aliases

   MySite::FeatureY::DataTypes::Messages => MS::Y::DT::Messages

   It's not pretty, but it might actually help. Check out EventMachine, they alias their long `EventMachine` module to `EM`. https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L1543-L1546

Comment: Thanks, (2) is doable and makes sense to me